# How to design the colour of barplot using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I use the ggplot to plot barplot, I want to set the highest value of attributes as a colour and set other attributes as same color, how can I do that? Like the following piture, I want to set the Run1 as red colour and other Runs as blue colour.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DtKgC.png

```
df <- data.frame(a=c("1","1","2","3","4","5"))
ggplot(df,aes(x=a,fill=a))+geom_bar
```

As in the example above, the colours are different, I want one colour for "1" and one colour for "2" to "5"

I want to control the colours automatically, but I can't control them with this setting.

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=a,fill=ifelse(a=="1","red","green")))+geom_bar()
```

Comment: Provide data and your code.

Comment: Have you looked at the `ggplot` documentation for `scale_fill_manual` https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_manual.html

Comment: @Bloxx  I add an example code.

Comment: @tjebo  It seems that scale_fill_manual should fill in each colour, I want to set only one and the other one.

Comment: ... you could also try with `+ scale_fill_identity(guide = "legend")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put your `ifelse(a=="1","red","green")` into the scale_fill_manual, e.g.

```r
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(a=c("1","1","2","3","4","5"))
ggplot(df,aes(x=a,fill=a)) +
  geom_bar() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = ifelse(df$a == 1, "red", "green"))
```

[image]

But this colours your first two bars because your the first two values in df$a == 1. Another solution is to create a new column in your dataframe called "group" and fill it with values based on "a", then use "group" as your 'fill' variable, e.g.

```r
df$group <- ifelse(df$a == 1, "group1", "group2")

ggplot(df, aes(x = a, fill = group)) +
  geom_bar() +
  scale_fill_viridis_d(begin = 0.2, end = 0.6)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-11-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

With the manual colours chosen:

```r
df$group <- ifelse(df$a == 1, "group1", "group2")
ggplot(df, aes(x = a, fill = group)) +
  geom_bar() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("group1" = "red",
                               "group2" = "green"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-11-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Since I am making a barplot, I wanted to highlight the one with the highest frequency category. It seems more appropriate to divide the highest frequency into one category and the others into one category and plot them.

Answer (score 0):

You have many options, but it looks like you want to simply set the color manually.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=as.factor(a), fill=as.factor(a)))+
  geom_bar() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue") )
```

if you would rather let ggplot set the color and pick the "largest" group to highlight, create a vector of equal length and pass it to the fill option like this (similar to Jared):

```
y  <- df %>% group_by(a) %>% count(a)
z  <- df %>% left_join(filter(y, n == max(y$n))) %>%
             mutate(grp = case_when(n > 0 ~ 1, T ~ 0))

ggplot(z, aes(x=a, fill=grp)) +
  geom_bar()
```

Comment: I want to control the colours automatically, like the following the code, but I can't control them with this setting. ggplot(df,aes(x=a,fill=ifelse(a=="1","red","green")))+geom_bar()

Answer (score 0):

The general idea behind ggplot is to have a column which the colour (or shape, size, other aesthetics are based on).

So modify your dataframe to have a column which matches up with the colours you want and it all become simple

```
df <- df %>% mutate(col = ifelse(a =="1","1","other"))
ggplot(df,aes(x=a,fill=col))+geom_bar()
```

Comment: It seems more appropriate to regroup the data and divide the colours by group.